# How to make variables accessible outside of their scope in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, scope

I am new to JavaScript and learning about scope.
I understand that there is Global Scope and Local Scope, but wanted to know if variables in the Local scope could be made available outside their scope.

Is this possible, and if so how?

Thank you to everyone with the quick responses.

I'm learning to program and I had an outline made up on topics to research from a programmer. They said there is a way and even though it is bad practice, this could be used as a developer tool and there are some scenarios this would be helpful in.

Comment: make them global. But this is a bad practice. Variable scopes exist for a reason.

Comment: You are asking for something that is fundamentally in opposition of itself.  If you make a local variable global, it is no longer local.  It's like saying "I want a giraffe, but I want it to be a lion".  Please add more detail and explain exactly what you're trying to do because this sounds very much like an XY problem.

Comment: There’s now also block scope. I also assume when you say local scope you mean “function” scope?

Comment: In most browser’s dev tools you can call `console.log` in your code and inspect the variable that way... Sometimes you can even right click the output and assign it to the global scope from there.

Answer (score -1):

You can assign them to [`globalThis`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/globalThis) (also known as `window` in the browser and `global` in node):

```js
function assignGlobal(x) {
  globalThis.globalVar = x;
}

console.log(globalThis.globalVar);

assignGlobal('foo');

console.log(globalThis.globalVar);
```

**WARNING:** This is generally considered bad practice. It is usually easy to restructure your code in a way that you don’t need to assign to the global scope ever.

For debugging you can often call `console.log(myObject)` and inspect it in your developer console (<kbd>f12</kbd> in chrome; <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>k</kbd> in firefox). You can then right click the output and select something like “Store as global variable”:

[image: console.log]

- Right Click → Save as global variable

[image: Save as global]

Comment: @SebastianSimon Thanks, fixed

Comment: Thanks, Rúnar for your answer. In your experience,  when would doing this be helpful?

Comment: @Becca In my experience, only when publishing a library for users that don’t have access to [ES Modules](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Modules) (e.g. for internet explorer 11). Personally I haven’t assigned to the global scope in years.

Comment: Thanks Rúnar!  Your answer and shared experience on this was really helpful. I accept this as the answer. I wish I could upvote but I don't have enough reputation.

Comment: @Becca Don’t worry about it. I’m sure you’ll get a positively resieved question at some point which will earn you the privilege of an up-vote ;-)